# How to access config map values in scalatest?

Tags: scala, command-line-arguments, scalatest

This is the situation - I am using scalatest and I have a test that involves using a database. When testing locally, the database host is one value, when testing on my testing server (jenkins), the database host is another value. I want to be able to specify the host as a command line argument when invoking `sbt test`.

It looks like scalatest allows you to pass in a command line argument which it then stores in a config map. What I'm unclear on is how exactly can I access this config map value from inside the test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`withFixture(OneArgTest)`](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/sharing_fixtures#withFixtureOneArgTest) (I recommend reading other sections of the document as well). Adapting slightly to your use-case (the example uses `FlatSpec`, but other testing styles are basically the same):

```
class ExampleSpec extends fixture.FlatSpec {

  type FixtureParam = DbConnection

  def withFixture(test: OneArgTest) = {
    val dbUrl = test.configMap.getRequired("dbUrl")
    val dbConnection = // use dbUrl

    try {
      withFixture(test.toNoArgTest(dbConnection))
    }
    finally dbConnection.close()
  }

  "Testing" should "be easy" in { dbConnection =>
    assert(dbConnection.isOpen)
  }
```

Comment: Seems like a good direction go towards, however the problem with that is I need the db client object to be visible to all the tests, which means I have to define it outside of any methods in the test. Would making the db client a var and assigning it a dummy value initially work? Even if it did it's kind of an ugly solution.

Comment: @JohnDoe Yes, that's what I'd do (except using `ThreadLocal` to handle parallel test execution).

Comment: I see, guess I'll try that then, thanks for hte help! Also, could you clarify what you mean by "(except using ThreadLocal to handle parallel test execution)"? I'm kind of new to this whole testing thing, and scala in general.

Comment: @JohnDoe Actually, there is a better fit for your use-case, see the new answer.

Comment: oooh, so you're saying `dbConnection` will be visible inside the tests, if defined inside `withFixture`?

Comment: It isn't "visible inside the tests", it is passed as argument to the tests.

Comment: `val dbConnection` in `withFixture` is a local variable. `{ dbConnection => ... }` is a function, and `dbConnection` is its parameter name. They don't have to be the same.

Comment: Oh I see, is there a way to make the tests accept two arguments instead of one? The reason why requires explaining a bit more about the context but I'd rather not complicate the question with that.

Comment: Right, read the docs on "sharing fixtures" that you linked and that seems to answer my question :)